# Get and multiply WooCommerce product formatted price to insert in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, woocommerce, product, price

I am Using this custom Function to show a modal pop up that tell client the monthly price based on product price. Currently it works well, the issue is that we need the amount to be multiplied by 4. This way when it calculates it can display the correct price per month.
--**Ex:** if price is $500.00 for set of 4 (tires) --> then monthly payments are based on 500 not 125 which is confusing customers.

Here is my code..need `'_price'`to be multiplied by *4

Can someone please help with solution.

```
function pb_modal() {
$pb_product_price = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_price', true);

$pb_product_format = number_format((float)$pb_product_price, 2, '.', '');
echo "<script id='pb_prequalify' type='text/javascript' src='https://app.paybright.com/dist/sdk.js?public_key=[MY API KEY]&financedamount=$$pb_product_format'></script>";
echo "<script>
pb_prequalify_init({
    triggerElement: 'link',  
    triggerText: 'Credit available with <br> Prequalify now',
    lang: 'en',
    hideTriggerLeadText: true,
    noFiguresInModal: true,
    });
</script>
";
    echo "<div id='paybright-widget-container'></div>";
  }
    add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_form', 'pb_modal', 1);
```

Comment: I don't understand the issue. You need to multiply the price. You have the price in `$pb_product_price`. What's preventing you to multiply this value by 4? What is it that I'm missing from your question?

Comment: I don't know how...to write it.

Comment: You're saying you don't know how to do [multiplication in PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php)?

Comment: Not yet still trying to learn, and also...your comment is a little rude and not needed. But if your car has an electrical issue...do you know how to fix it? Im sure you know how to replace a spare though....so everyone at different levels...this is why we help each other and shouldn't belittle one another!!

Comment: I'm sorry if it came off as condescending, that wasn't my intention. I really wasn't sure if this is all that there is to your issue or maybe I was missing something. Honestly, I was baffled that a question might concern something as basic as that. With that being said - this is tutorial territory and not really SO material.

Comment: Thank you, yes its basic I know. I am still learning only 7 months (on the side) ...advanced quite a bit but damn something as simple as this...I just don't get how to write it...I see different versions for same purpose...and hate braking my site for a simple affair like this... I agree with the tutorial territory..but i still need solution. Show me once...and then I learn from studying it! I know its simple. I agree. But not for me at this very moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated** - You can use the following to get the raw product price for display, to multiply it by 4 and format it in the right way:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_form', 'wc_pb_modal', 1 );
function wc_pb_modal() {
    global $product;
    
    if ( ! is_a($product, 'WC_Product') ) {
        $product = wc_get_product(get_the_ID());
    }

    if ( $product->is_type('variable') ) {
        return; // Exit if a variable product
    }

    $formatted_price = strip_tags( wc_price( wc_get_price_to_display( $product ) * 4 ) );
    $my_api_key      = '[MY API KEY]'; // Here set your api key
    
    echo "<script id='pb_prequalify' type='text/javascript' src='https://app.paybright.com/dist/sdk.js?public_key=$my_api_key&financedamount=$formatted_price'></script>
    <script>
    pb_prequalify_init({
        triggerElement: 'link',  
        triggerText: 'Credit available with <br> Prequalify now',
        lang: 'en',
        hideTriggerLeadText: true,
        noFiguresInModal: true,
    });
    </script>
    <div id='paybright-widget-container'></div>";
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). It should work.

Comment: Correct price is displayed as monthly payment now. Yay!